# Python: Without Itertools, how do I aggregate values in a list of lists for only the years that are included in that list?

Tags: while-loop, python-3.7, iterable

I'm attempting to iterate over a list of lists that includes a date range of 1978-2020, but with only built-in Python modules.  For instance, my nested list looks something like:

```
listing =[['0010', 'green', '1978', 'light'], ['0020', 'blue', '1978', 'dark'], ... ['2510', 'red', '2020', 'light']]
```

As I am iterating through, I am trying to make an aggregated count of colors and shades for that year, and then append that year's totals into a new list such as:

```
# ['year', 'blues', 'greens', 'light', dark']
annual_totals = [['1978', 12, 34, 8, 16], ['1979', 14, 40, 13, 9], ... , ['2020', 48, 98, 14, 10]]
```

So my failed code looks something like this:

```
annual_totals = []

for i in range(1978, 2021):
    for line in listing:
        while i == line[2]  #if year in list same as year in iterated range, count tally for year
        blue = 0
        green = 0
        light = 0
        dark = 0            
            if line[1] == 'blue'
               blue += 1
            if line[1] == 'green'
               blue += 1
            if line[3] == 'light'
               light += 1
            if line[3] == 'dark'
               dark += 1

            tally = [i, 'blue', 'green', 'light', dark']
            annual_totals.append(tally)
```

Of course, I never get out of the While loop to get a new year for iterable i.

Comment: I would recommend you to use **pandas** library instead of going with the list of list code, where you can use **groupby** operation on multiple columns depending on your requirements. That would be more efficient. The reason I am saying this is because if this tally goes to **daybyday** or *hourbyhour** You will be having bad looping and overcomplexity of your solution. Go for Columnar Pandas advantages.

Comment: I appreciate the thoughts. Unfortunately the system is constrained to built-in modules.